# Flutter - Accessing JSON stored image and displaying in listview

Tags: json, image, dart, flutter

For my Flutter app, I want to display the JSON data image into a listview. Below i have typed out a short example of my data.

Currently i am grabbing my data using:

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async {
var response = await 
rootBundle.loadString('assests/data/test.json');

this.setState(() {
  var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response);
  data = convertDataToJson;
});
```

I am outputting my data using:

```
child: new Text(data[index]['text'])
```

How do i output the img that is stored?

```
Img: "PB:29110b176efb5c79_normal.jpeg"
```

Comment: What does "image that is stored" mean? Is it binary image data, or is it the name (and path) of an image file?

Comment: I don't quite know, I am very new to using Flutter and JSON, in the JSON file the field img is stored as "PB:29110b176efb5c79_normal.jpeg", i just want to display this image to the app

Comment: `"PB:29110b176efb5c79_normal.jpeg"` is only a string, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have those images in `assets/` directory and added those images in `pubspec.yaml` file as shown below:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/image01.jpg
    - assets/image02.jpg
```

You can also mention directory in case you have many files as shown below:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

If these two requirements are already fulfilled, you can easily display images using below code:

```
Image.asset(data[index]['Img']);
```

Image path in JSON should be correctly mapped with assets directory.

Comment: I have not put the images in the assets directory as the JSON file has over 200 entries that all have images linked to the data. Is this my only option?

Comment: Where do you have those images? In assets directory or images are on Network(Like S3 or somewhere else).

Comment: the JSON file is stored in assests/data/test.json. The file was originally taken from a mongodb cluster but we were unable to use the cluster so we imported it. We don't have information where the data was taken from originally

Comment: You can look at the updated answer. You can also mention directory name. In that case, you don't have to specify individual files.